# Rewrite URL using .htaccess file in case there is used parameters which is not in white list

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Need to achieve the following: 
Rewrite URL using .htaccess file in case there is used parameters which is not in white list.

Example:
Whitelisted parameters: phone, fax, zip

```
Input URL:     http://hostname/adress?phone=1234567890
Resulting URL: http://hostname/adress?phone=1234567890

Input URL:     http://hostname/contacts?fax=1234567
Resulting URL: http://hostname/contacts?fax=1234567

Input URL:     http://hostname/test?zip=1234
Resulting URL: http://hostname/test?zip=1234

Input URL:     http://hostname/test?phoneHack=1234567890
Resulting URL: http://hostname/test

Input URL:     http://hostname/mytest?anotherParam=1234567890
Resulting URL: http://hostname/mytest
```

So far my findings:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(phone|fax|zip)
RewriteRule .* http://hostname/%{REQUEST_URI}?%{QUERY_STRING}
```

Tool where to test: http://martinmelin.se/rewrite-rule-tester/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this rule with negation:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.+$
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^(phone|fax|zip)= [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]
```

`?` in the end is for stripping out QUERY_STRING from original URL.

Comment: Thank you for suggestion. It somehow works, but not till the end.
I replaced second line with the following: "RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}? [L,R=301]" because is needed to let "test" part be flexible, but in this case browser says: "This webpage has a redirect loop".

Comment: So do you just want to strip query string is parameter is NOT one of phone, fax, zip?

Comment: So far seems perfect! :)
But I just noticed that need even more complex solution.
I need to strip any parameter, e.g. URL: "abc.com/somePage?phone=1234&stipAway=asd&fax=324&stripDown=disappear&zip=zip" should look "abc.com/somePage?phone=1234&fax=324&zip=zip"

Comment: @Martins: That is like changing the very nature of the question. Comments are usually to discuss to issues with the posted question and answer not for changing the question itself. I would suggest opening a new question with that requirement since that answer will be very different and don't forget to mark this as accepted.

Comment: Oh sure no problems at all, did you create a new question?

Comment: Yes, it is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19765171/strip-down-any-parameter-from-url-which-is-not-whitelisted)

Comment: Ok let me try to address it.