# Strip down any parameter from URL which is not whitelisted

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need to strip **any** parameter which is not in white list e.g. URL:

```
abc.com/somePage?phone=1234&stipAway=asd&fax=324&stripDown=disappear&zip=zip
```

should look:

```
abc.com/somePage?phone=1234&fax=324&zip=zip
```

Related question: [Rewrite URL using .htaccess file in case there is used parameters which is not in white list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19728136/rewrite-url-using-htaccess-file-in-case-there-is-used-parameters-which-is-not-i)

P.S. It is more complex solution needed that in first two answers mentioned. To make understandable I will illustrate with some more examples:

```
abc.com/somePage2?stripAway=asd&fax=324&stripDown=disappear&phone=1234&zip=zip
```

should look:

```
abc.com/somePage2?fax=324&phone=1234&zip=zip
```

and

```
abc.com/somePage3?stripAway=asd&stripDown=disappear
```

should look:

```
abc.com/somePage3
```

Comment: I've edited my answer with a method if not all parameters are present. I would recommend doing this on the page itself though.

Comment: @Martins: Sorry I couldn't attend this problem yesterday. I am sure there will be some pure .htaccess way of doing this also. I will try it today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the list is in order, anubhava's answer is much better than mine. If the list is not guaranteed to be in order, you can use the following rule. It uses the technique that [Jon Lin uses in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17793597/2209007).

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}           ^(.*&|)(?!(phone|fax|zip))[^=]+=
RewriteCond ##%{QUERY_STRING}         (.*?)##(|.*&)(phone)=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %1&%3=%4##%{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)##(|.*&)(fax)=([^&]+)
RewriteCond %1&%3=%4##%{QUERY_STRING} (.*?)##(|.*&)(zip)=([^&]+)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%3=%4%1 [R,L]
```

So, what does it do? The first condition is only true if it can find a parameter that does not match `(phone|fax|zip)` (negative look-ahead). The next three `RewriteCond` capture each of the parameters you want to keep and prepare a query string before the custom `##` separator. Strange things will happen if that separator happens to be in your query string.

The downside of this approach is, if one of these three parameters is not present, the rule will not be applied. I would personally put this whitelist in the page itself, and not try to filter it via .htaccess.

---

Edit: If some parameters are optional, you can use the following monstrosity:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^((.*?)&|)(?!(phone|fax|zip))[^=]+=[^&]+(&.*|)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%2%4 [R,E=Redir:1]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^&(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1?%1 [R,E=Redir:1]

RewriteCond %{ENV:Redir} =1
RewriteRule ^ - [R,L]
```

Basically, if there is parameter in the string that does not match the parameters in the lookahead, it will match the part before that parameter and the part behind that parameter and reforge a query string. The second rule is to prevent it from devouring the entire query string if the first parameter is not 'whitelisted' (or it just simply starts with a &) and the last rule is to try to keep the amount of redirects to a minimum. Please note that if there are too many parameters in the request that are not whitelisted, the browser will display an error (redirect chain detected).

---

Instead I would recommend filtering on the page itself. In php it would be something like the following code. This will make it easier to maintain this whitelist and doesn't break everything if you ever decide to use an other httpdeamon.

```
<?php
$whitelist = Array( 'phone', 'fax', 'zip' );
foreach( $_GET as $k => $v ) {
  if( !in_array( $k, $whitelist ) )
    unset( $_GET[$k] );
}

#And the same for $_POST and $_REQUEST
```

Comment: Thank you @Sumurai8 for explanation. I will use approach with handling it in application.

Answer (score 1):

Following should work for you:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(?:.*?&)?(phone=[^&]*)(?:.*?&)(fax=[^&]*)(?:.*?&)(zip=[^&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %{REQUEST_URI}?%1%2%3 [L,R=302]
```

*PS: This is assuming white list params appear in the above order i.e. phone, fax, zip*

Comment: Thanks for sharing nice answer sir. One question shouldn't we use `?` at the last of RewriteRule for removal of query sting if there are any? Thank you,

Comment: `?` is not needed again in target because we are already using it

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact use case, and I landed on the following solution. It will work as long as there are not more than 9 query params on the URL to begin with. Not sure if this is a good way to do it, but it works. Order of the parameters don't matter, and they are all optional.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (?:((?:(?:phone)|(?:fax)|(?:zip))=?[^&\s]*&?)|[^&\s]*&)?(?:(\g'1')|[^&\s]*&)?(?:(\g'1')|[^&\s]*&)?(?:(\g'1')|[^&\s]*&)?(?:(\g'1')|[^&\s]*&)?(?:(\g'1')|[^&\s]*&)?(?:(\g'1')|[^&\s]*&)?(?:(\g'1')|[^&\s]*&)?(?:(\g'1')|[^&\s]*&)
RewriteRule "^(.*)$" "$1?%1%2%3%4%5%6%7%8%9" [PT,NC]
```